# Hive Metastore high availability

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, high-availability, metastore

Under cloudera, i'm trying to configure hive metastore to be highly available.

So i followed the tutorial bellow : http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hive_metastore_configure.html

My question is : do i need to add load balancers between hive metastore server and the replicated databases ?

Cause i think that we either need to give a list of URIs of the databases to hive metastore servers or to use a load balancer to switch to an other database in case of failure.

thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't find anything HA-related by following the link you've provided. Perhaps you might want to look at http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_ha_hivemetastore.html. Take into account that metastore HA doesn't imply database HA.

Comment: I did a miss copy/past, the link that you provided to me, is the one that i used to configure my Hive Meta Store HA, and the question is related to the communication with a  HA database, so do i need to add loadbalancer between the HA Meta stores and HA databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to my question :

actually the answer depends on the database, if the database manages HA and failover, there is no need to have loadbalancers , otherwise we need it in case of failure.

for the configuration part we can put as many uris as dbs in the hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://myhost/metastore,</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>
```

Comment: I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee

hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794

Here is file-structure 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e02b3631da940dfae880252ca72107de